# invalid grant when trying to get token for azure AD graph api

Tags: azure

I am fighting invalid_grant error when exchanging code to graph token in OIDC middleware:

I have had stuff like this working before, but cant seem to find the difference form this and the samples. heres the code to try get a token for azure AD Graph api:

```
AuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
{
    try
    {

    string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("oid").Value;
    string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("tid").Value;

    var credential = GetCredential(); 
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", tenantID));
                                Uri redirectUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));
    Logger.InfoFormat("redirect {0}", redirectUri);
    AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
        context.Code, redirectUri, credential, graphResourceID);
   }catch(Exception ex)
   {
       Logger.ErrorException("oidc", ex);
   }
}
```

but got a

```
1/17/2015 4:22:42 AM: a0e69d43-1c91-4069-8d1f-4b03103dc227 - AsyncMethodBuilderCore: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS70000: The provided access grant is invalid or malformed.
Trace ID: 2112568f-fbe6-4ac6-bd67-de5904a9b9f5
Correlation ID: a0e69d43-1c91-4069-8d1f-4b03103dc227
Timestamp: 2015-01-17 04:22:42Z
```

Application permission is set to read data.
delegated permission is set to read user profile.

Am I right that above is not sufficient, that i also need to create a authorization request for the graph resource after the user signed in.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is make sure you handle your tailing slashes correctly!

The redirect must be the same as when you started the token exchange, this means that when you start the redirect to authorization endpoint, the redirect uri used there needs to be the same as when you exchange code to token at token endpoint.

A good way to do this is by using

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = async (context) =>
{
                         string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                         context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                         context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
}
```

which i also did, but i forgot the tailing slash. Now it will be identical to what you get when doing

```
Uri redirectUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));
```